# 'Monodromy' for relative homology group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology

Let $A$ and $X$ be topological manifolds. Denote by $\mathbb {Emb}(A,X)$ the space of all topological embeddings $A\to X$.

A loop $f_s:A\to X$ ($s\in[0,1]$) in $\mathbb{Emb}(A,X)$ should give rise to an isomorphism
$$\Phi: H_k(X,f_0(A))\cong H_k(X,f_0(A))$$
by identifying $H_k(X,f_s(A))$ with $H_k(X,f_{s+\epsilon}(A))$ for all $s$ and sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$.

Suppose the space $\mathbb{Emb}(A,X)$ is not simply-connected and the loop $f_s$ is not contractible in this space.
Then, we may think of $\Phi$ as a 'monodromy' map. For simplicity, we may further assume $A$ is compact and $k\ge 2$, etc.

**Question**: By what conditions can we ensure the 'monodromy' is trivial, i.e. $\Phi=id$?

The example in my mind is as follows: we have a elliptic K3 surface $g:X\to\mathbb P^1$. Most fibers of $g$ are topologically torus $T^2$ and there are finitely many singular fibers which are 'pinched sphere'. Let $z_0\in \mathbb P^1$ be a singular value and take a small loop $\gamma$ centered at $z_0$; then the torus fibers over $\gamma$ gives rise to a loop in $\mathbb{Emb}(T^2,X)$ and I would like to study $H_2(X, g^{-1}(z))$ for $z\in \gamma$.

Comment: Nitpick: Is the monodromy in the traditional sense (the map $A \to A$ you get by moving around that loop in the fiber) trivial for the K3 surface? If not, what you mean is not $\text{Emb}(A,X)$ but rather $\text{Sub}(A,X)$, the space of subspaces homeomorphic to $A$. Equivalently, $\text{Emb}(A,X)/\text{Homeo}(A)$. Loops in this space still give rise to monodromy on relative homology.